# How to read a excel file without choose file option through controller using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, excel, mongodb, github

I want to show the excel file on UI, I would be getting the excel file path from MongoDB. I want to show this file on UI

The excel file should look like this on UI:

[image]

I tried  github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx and was able to get the excel data in JSON format on UI, but I need to show the excel data in grid.
So for this, I used ui-grid like this in my HTML:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };

});//Passed some hard code values here,
```

I need to pass the excel data instead of this data, but through js-xlsx I am getting the JSON data on UI itself, how to pass this values to ui-grid.? So, that i can show the excel data in grid on UI.

Please help me on this. Need help on this.